# What is the probability density function over time for a 1-D random walk on a line with boundaries?

Tags: probability, diffusion, stochastic-processes

If a single particle sits on an infinite line and undergoes a 1-D random walk, the probability density of its spatio-temporal evolution is captured by a 1-D gaussian distribution.

\begin{align}
P(x,t)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi D t}}e^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{4Dt}}
\end{align}

However, suppose there are impassable boundaries on the line; on one side, or on both sides. Are there any boundary conditions for which there exists a closed form probability density function for how this particle will behave over time? Any references to such solutions would be extraordinarily helpful.

EDIT. Attempting to generalize Emilio's result below for an arbitrary initial particle position $-L/2 < x_0 < L/2$.

I had to work it out by example. I found the following "images" were required to account for reflections of an off-center particle at position $x_0$: for the first and second reflections on both sides the new gaussians had to be centered on ($-2L+x_0$, $-L-x_0$, $x_0$, $L-x_0$, $2L+x_0$). From the pattern I think the full solution can be expressed, for all integers $n$, as:

\begin{align}
P(x,t)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi D t}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{(x-nL-(-1)^nx_0)^2}{4Dt}}
\end{align}

where the old $x_0$ is now defined as $nL+(-1)^{n}x_0$

Comment: what type of steps are you taking? Also, what do you mean be "impassible"? Do you mean you reject any step that takes you over the boundary?

Comment: Periodic boundary conditions spring to mind.

Comment: General word of advice: "closed form" isn't terribly well defined. What people generally mean is "in terms of nice functions that I like and understand" but this is clearly subjective. There are *many* solutions to physically-inspired math problems are perfectly well-behaved and analytic, but that no one has bothered assigning abbreviations to like $\mathrm{e}$, $\sin$ or $J_0$. These functions are still manipulable and easily calculable to arbitrary precision.

Comment: Why is there a closevote on this? It is a perfectly legitimate, well defined and well formulated question.

Comment: @MikeFlynn exactly. There are multiple ways to impose a boundary condition where particles are not permitted to pass beyond, and I'm interested for now in any of those conditions.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Advice taken, and I admit that even solutions which require numerical estimation are potentially usable for my problem. On the other hand, I'm not a math wiz so I'm progressively less comfortable the more sophisticated the solution. I'm already well out of my depth.

Comment: Regarding @MikeFlynn comment, your particles could 1) bounce off the barrier, 2) stop at the barrier, 3) if they hit the barrier consider that an invalid move and try again. These make a big difference in what the distribution is.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey How are 1 and 3 different? Unless there is a time lag (and how on Earth would you implement that?), operationally they look exactly the same to me.

Comment: Rejecting a trajectory that crosses a boundary, as in 3, sounds algorithmic, not physical to me.

Comment: @Emilio: For 1) I was thinking about a ball bouncing, where it does not have to bounce back to where it started. For 3) I was thinking if the trajectory of the ball would hit the wall, that trajectory is simply not attempted, it is rejected.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey so where does the ball go?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Can you look over my edits above Emilio? Does that look like what you were thinking for an asymmetric start position?

Comment: Almost but not quite. Note that you will need _two_ independent series of particles spaced by $2L$, as the symmetry is broken. (Think of standing between to mirrors quite close to one of them. You will see many pairs of yourself.) Thus for a particle at $x_0$ and mirrors at $\pm L/2$, you will have one series at $x_0+2L n$ and one at $L-x_0+2Ln=(2n+1)L-x_0$. (For $x_0=0$, of course they reduce to a single series at $nL$.) Each of these will sum to a different theta function, though you might find a way to join the two terms in the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I think your two series and my series are the same. For my series, n=-2 to 2 yields $-2L+x_0$, $-L-x_0$, $x_0$, $L-x_0$, $2L+x_0$, and I think this is the same as your first series summed for n=-1 to 1 ($-2L+x_0$, $x_0$, $2L+x_0$) plus your second series for n=-1 to 0 ($-L-x_0$, $L-x_0$). I'm not quite sure how to use the theta functions yet, still digesting that piece.

Comment: OK, then: if it matches, it matches. It will be hard to get it to match a theta function in the $(-1)^n x_0$ form, though.

Comment: The theta functions are useful if you want to graph them or calculate them as they go down a lot easier on your computational resources, but they're not necessary and it depends on what you want from your solution. I summed the series using Mathematica, but you can get it from [DLMF 20.2.3](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.2.E3) by unfolding $\cos(2nz)=\frac12(e^{2inz}+e^{-2inz})$ and massaging your expression to match that form. Once in theta-function form, you've got the full weight of the DLMF to manipulate it and any CAS will graph it easily. What _do_ you want out of that solution, anyway?

Comment: That DLMF is a great resource, good to know about. I'll play with the theta functions when I get a chance. As for purpose, that's rather complicated. I'm trying to build a simulation of something in biology, and this is the simplest case. To be honest I didn't think I would be able to solve even this base case problem but your approach is so elegant and scalable I think I might have a chance at solving the full problem. Fortuitously, I think reflecting boundary conditions are the optimal conditions for my problem.

Comment: See also [Physical Applications](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.13).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can probably be solved by the method of images, depending on your precise formulation of the problem. The main idea would be to place image particles at the initial time at positions given by treating your impassable boundaries as mirrors; this makes the probability flow at the boundary zero.

To give a more precise formulation, suppose your problem is
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial x^2}\text{ under }\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(-L/2,t)=0=\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(L/2,t)\text{ and }P(x,0)=\delta(x),
$$
where I've initially placed the particle in the middle of the barriers for simplicity but this can be altered. The solution is then given, by linearity, by your expression, added up for $x_0=nL$ for all integers $n$:
$$
P(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi D t}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{(x-nL)^2}{4Dt}}.
$$
This can be solved exactly in terms of [Jacobi theta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function), which makes the calculations and graphing a lot faster, but does not necessarily (at a first go) make this easier to work with:
$$
P(x,t)=\frac{1}{L}\vartheta _3\left(\frac{\pi  x}{L},e^{-\frac{4 D \pi ^2 t}{L^2}}\right).
$$
(For asymetrically placed initial particles, you would have two series of gaussians separated by $2L$, so therefore two theta functions.)

I'm not sure this is very useful by itself, but the method of images is very powerful.

Comment: There was also good fun in taking $P\mapsto\psi$ to be a wavefunction. This forces you to re-normalize, and the dependence of this factor on $D$, if I remember correctly, are a nice exercise for someone with much too much time on their hands.

Comment: Just a comment on series solutions: I think your example converges pretty quickly, but with different boundary conditions the convergence can be very slow. It is worth trying the [Poisson summation theorem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5831) in these cases. In the linked case Poisson summation unexpectedly collapsed a numerically awful series (thousands of terms needed) to a very simple analytic solution.

Comment: Interesting, I need to digest this. What exactly does a mirror boundary imply? Is it equivalent to saying that for a specific particle trajectory, a particle that might have traveled distance $x_a+x_b$, where $x_a$ is the distance to the boundary, and $x_b$ is the distance it might have traveled past the boundary, instead travels distance $x_a-x_b$?

Comment: @vector07 Yeah, that's about it. You "fold back" all trajectories at the boundary, which means the boundary has probability 1 of reflecting. For every trajectory that travels $x_a-x_b$ there are then equally many that go left as well as right, so that mid-interval points still have probability 1/2 for right and left.

Comment: It is easier, though, to re-think the "folding back" as adding another mirrored copy of your trajectory tree behind the "mirror" at the boundary.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I think I get it, that helps a lot. I think I've generalized it to the case where the initial position is anywhere between -L/2 and L/2, but would you mind checking my work?

Comment: + This looks like a great answer, though in my laziness I wonder if it comes out to some simple known distribution, like Beta.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is in fact a particular solution of the 1-Dimensional [heat equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation), $\frac{\partial  P}{\partial t}  = D \frac{\partial^2  P}{\partial x^2}$,with initial condition $P(x,0) = \delta (x-x_0)$

A traditionnal way to solve this equation is to use [Fourier Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Solving_the_heat_equation_using_Fourier_series)

See some solutions in [1-D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Some_Green.27s_function_solutions_in_1D), like [homogeneous equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Homogeneous_heat_equation) or [inhomogeneous equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Inhomogeneous_heat_equation), or other [examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Examples)